# Install Ubuntu 12.04 as a replacement for Windows XP

Tags: system-installation, windows

I am running the installation right now and I have not seen an option to install in place of Window XP which is currently installed on this computer. Will I be given that option after the install?

Comment: You have to boot the computer from the Live USB/CD/DVD to replace Windows. You will not get this option if you try to install Ubuntu from within Windows. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

Comment: you cna install ubuntu along side windows....

Answer (score 0):

the true way of installing ubuntu is first change the boot priority in bios ,then restart your system ..it will automatically detects your USB/CD-ROM containing installation file , then just click Install Ubuntu after onw or two steps you will get a window asking where to install ubuntu with three choices ,Along side Windows, replace windows and install ubuntu lastly something else.. i would say not to use something else if you are not familiar with Linux disk management . thats it .